# JTree not updating (need clarification)

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

Here is the problem:

I have a main panel, that has 3 sub panel containing an status update area, projectlistTree panel and a analysis panel.

The projectlist tree panel needs two clases:

1. One a panel clas that contains the user interface components.
2. A treelist model class that provides the treemodel for the jtree.

What I have tried:

Once new project is created and saved, the tree should be updated and it should appear on the projectlisttree panel.

Based on the many answers on SO, I created a method set and get treemodel, and when ever the project is saved, the model is set again. And basically jtree tree model is set using getmodel method that I have created.

How the model should be set and called?

Here is the set and get treemodel methods:

The following set and get methods are in class common.java

```
  public FileSystemModel getFsModel() {
return fsModel;
}

public void setFsModel(FileSystemModel fsModel) {
    this.fsModel = fsModel;
}
```

Here is the treemodel class

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;


class FileSystemModel implements TreeModel {

  private File root;
  private Vector listeners = new Vector();

  public FileSystemModel(File rootDirectory) {
    root = rootDirectory;
  }

  public Object getRoot() {
    return root;
  }

  public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    String[] children = directory.list();
    return new TreeFile(directory, children[index]);
  }

  public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    File file = (File) parent;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      String[] fileList = file.list();
      if (fileList != null)
    return file.list().length;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    File file = (File) node;
    return file.isFile();
  }

  public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    File file = (File) child;
    String[] children = directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (file.getName().equals(children[i])) {
    return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;

  }

  public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object value) {
    File oldFile = (File) path.getLastPathComponent();
    String fileParentPath = oldFile.getParent();
    String newFileName = (String) value;
    File targetFile = new File(fileParentPath, newFileName);
    oldFile.renameTo(targetFile);
    File parent = new File(fileParentPath);
    int[] changedChildrenIndices = { getIndexOfChild(parent, targetFile) };
    Object[] changedChildren = { targetFile };
    fireTreeNodesChanged(path.getParentPath(), changedChildrenIndices, changedChildren);

  }

  private void fireTreeNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices, Object[] children) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices, children);
    Iterator iterator = listeners.iterator();
    TreeModelListener listener = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      listener = (TreeModelListener) iterator.next();
      listener.treeNodesChanged(event);
    }
  }

  public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }

  private class TreeFile extends File {
    public TreeFile(File parent, String child) {
      super(parent, child);
    }

    public String toString() {
       return getName();
          }
      }
      }
```

the Jtree panel:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package analysisui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class ShowProjectTree extends JPanel {

    private FileSystemModel fileSystemModel;
    Common commonCls;

    /**
     * Creates new form ShowProjectTree
     */
    public ShowProjectTree(Common cmnClas) {
    commonCls = cmnClas;
    initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    fileSystemModel = commonCls.getFsModel();
    proListTree = new javax.swing.JTree(fileSystemModel);

    revalidate();
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(proListTree);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 295, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 434, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    }// </editor-fold>

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree proListTree;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

So once i saved a new project to the project folder,the set model method is called.

```
       commonCls.setAppendMessage("\n>>"+projectName + " created \n");
       revalidate();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you set the new model on the tree ? That is not shown in your getter/setter

Comment: Thanks,Yeah just found tat :)now its working well

Comment: You can [answer (or delete) your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).